# converting list of same key/value json to another dictionary list with common key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I just started working on huge data sets with python script. I have specific json which is pretty large (just sample example below) which I need to convert to another form of list of dictionary having same key as:

original json:

```
{
    "111": [
        {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": 1,
            "key3": "value3"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value2",
            "key2": 2,
            "key3": "value3"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value4",
            "key2": 10,
            "key5": "value5"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value6",
            "key2": 11,
            "key5": "value5"
        }
    ]
}
```

output:

```
{
"111": [
    {
        "value3": [
            {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": 1
            },
            {
                "key1": "value2",
                "key2": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "value5": [
            {
                "key1": "value4",
                "key2": 10
            },
            {
                "key1": "value6",
                "key2": 11
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

any easy way without having too many for loops in python3? NOTE: value if key3 and key 5 is the new key in output json

Comment: did you try anything to come to the conclusion of too many loops? if so, edit question with what you have tried

Comment: but you dont say whick are the keys for the nee arrengment in;general.